# how to escape `&>` in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I use a :

```
python notation.py &> notation.log
```

Command line.

I try to run it from a Makefile with no success:

```
$ cat Makefile 
run:
    python notation.py &> notation.log
$ make
$ ls -la notation.log 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 juin   8 08:15 notation.log
$
```

Comment: I don't get it. The file is there. What is it you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not escaping.  The problem is that is not legal syntax in the shell.

Make always invokes (by default) `/bin/sh` as the shell to run its recipes.  `/bin/sh` is a POSIX-standard shell.  The token `&>` is not valid POSIX shell syntax.  When you are logged in at a shell prompt you are not running the shell `/bin/sh`, you are running a more powerful shell, probably `bash` (on Linux) or possibly `zsh` (on newer MacOS systems).  These shells have extra features that are not defined in POSIX and not available in a POSIX-compliant version of `/bin/sh`.

You have two choices: either use correct POSIX syntax in your recipe:

```
run:
        python notation.py > notation.log 2>&1
```

Or else tell make to use your shell when it runs recipes:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

run:
        python notation.py &> notation.log
```

(of course this assumes that all systems you want to run your makefile in, actually have `/bin/bash` installed)